# How to improve my tables and queries for Big Data applications?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, bigdata

I created an API on Symfony which produces more than 1 million entries by day into one of the MySql tables. This table structure is defined this way:

[image]

After some weeks of use, the table has already 35 million (not trillion) of rows. And when I query this table, the response time is almost 20 seconds for a simple query like this one:

```
public function findAllCryptosByRank($date_minute)
{
    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("cm")
        ->from("APIBundle:CoinmarketcapSnapshot", "cm")
        ->where("cm.date_minute = :date_minute")
        ->orderBy("cm.rank", "ASC")
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'date_minute' => $date_minute,
        ));
    $finalQuery = $query->getQuery();
    return $finalQuery->getArrayResult();
}
```

When doing something more complicated, it's even worse; the queries take more than one minute. For example for something like that:

```
public function findAllCryptosByRank($date_minute,$date_hour,$date_day,$date_month,$date_year)
{
    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("cm", "c.logo", "c.title")
        ->from("APIBundle:CoinmarketcapSnapshot", "cm")
        ->where("cm.date_minute = :date_minute")
        ->andWhere("cm.date_hour = :date_hour")
        ->andWhere("cm.date_day = :date_day")
        ->andWhere("cm.date_month = :date_month")
        ->andWhere("cm.date_year = :date_year")
        ->leftJoin(
            'APIBundle:Cryptocurrency',
            'c',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'cm.cryptocurrency__id = c. coinmarketcap_id'
        )
        ->orderBy("cm.rank", "ASC")
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->setParameters(array('date_minute'=>$date_minute,'date_hour'=>$date_hour,'date_day'=>$date_day,'date_month'=>$date_month,'date_year'=>$date_year))
    ;
    $finalQuery = $query->getQuery();
    return $finalQuery->getArrayResult();
}
```

So, what can I do to hugely improve these performance? I read about Doctrine, that was not designed for Big Data use cases.

I know it's possible to improve MySQL performance by using tools such has Hadoop, or by optimising indexes for example.

But will this be enough regarding the very low performances at this moment?

I want to be sure Symfony is the good choice for this application. I am considering migrating the API to another Backend Framework, such as ASP.NET or Node.JS. What do you think?

Comment: The best way to do that is to use elasticsearch.

Comment: first of all verify the query use the right index or if the query could be optimized

Comment: I think it is not the framework that you should be concerned about, but the database itself. You need a db for big data if you plan to work with trillion records. You can easily access other databases besides MySQL in Symfony, and you can apply great optimizations, but MySQL will become a bottleneck eventually

Comment: At only a million rows a day, it will take 95,890 _centuries_ to amass 35 trillion rows!

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't treat Doctrine as an inseparable part of Symfony. You are free to remove it and switch to a different ORM implementation, or maybe skip Doctrine ORM and just use the DBAL instead. Also, sometimes removing the overhead of ORM or [iterating the result sets](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing) might give you a performance upgrade.

Second, this is not about Symfony or Doctrine, this is actually about the way you organize data in your application. The question you should be asking is whether you use the right tool for the job. As suggested in several comments, you could switch the storage completely (like, for example, use ElasticSearch as storage).

And also you should definitely use the typical query optimization techniques (like, run an `EXPLAIN` query and see where's the bottleneck).

Comment: The author is not using good tools for managing big data... Php nor MySQL are good choices.

Comment: @russellhoff, which framework do you suggest for big data use cases?

Comment: @kix, I know Doctrine is not mandatory when using Symfony, but I chose Symfony beside Laravel, specifically for Doctrine because I love it. I didn't know it was not good for Big Data performances

Comment: I would not choose PHP for Big Data due to the nature of PHP. You need a language that lets you manage millions of records, and PHP isn't definitely the best choice, since it has a maximum execution time per each script. I would choose languages such as Java or Python. And as for database, choose any other than MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

- Learn about indexing.  That particular query (which seems weird) needs `INDEX(date_minute, rank).
- Do the math:  There is no disk made that can accept 35 trillion rows in a few weeks.
- Your `INT SIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` has a limit of 2 billion.  That won't support 35 trillion rows.
- Don't split date/time values into multiple columns.
- Don't use 4-byte `INT` for 1-byte quantities such as "date_minute".  See `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.
- Use numeric datatypes (not `LONGTEXT`) for numeric values (volume, market cap, etc).
- Don't include `created` and `updated` unless you expect to actually do anything with those columns.  (3rd packages seem to like generating them, but then don't use them.)

I'm harping on datatypes because the table will get very big; shrinking the datatypes where possible will help it fit into your limited disk, and will help speed up queries.

Comment: Yes you are true, not 35 trillion but 35 million actually. I can confirm the first point, after I added an index to the "rank" column, the same query is now taking less than 1 second.